# How to implement a pedometer in CoronaSDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, pedometer

I'm trying to create a pedometer for an app that I'm coding in CoronaSDK, though I'm not really sure where to start.
I know that I need to create an algorithm/equation from the accelerometer data that is accessible.
(https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/accelerometer/index.html).

Any help or hints with an algorithm would be appreciated.

Comment: please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what Coronalabs says about this:

> Corona SDK does not have any API's or any plugins that can count
>   steps. However you do have access to the acceleromenter which gets you
>   the raw data on the device's movement and compute steps yourself, but
>   this will only work while the phone is awake and the app is in the
>   foreground. Corona SDK is not designed to run in the background. There
>   is an assumption that there is a screen to draw to each frame.
>
> We do have a product called Corona Enterprise that lets you talk to
>   other native SDKs. You could use it to collect your native data and
>   **in theory** have it run in the background and when the app wakes up, send the collected data to the Lua/Corona portion of the app to
>   display.

So if this doesn't stop you you could try to implement this:

[Opening the Black Box: Publishing Pebble’s activity-tracking algorithms](https://medium.com/pebble-research/opening-the-black-box-publishing-pebbles-activity-tracking-algorithms-bebdb5a7383a) where they basically look for the most rhythmic frequency within a 5 second interval. If the calculated score is above a certain threshold it's considered running or walking.